# How to remove the port after nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

So I want to redirect the requests from port 80 to 8049 and from 443 to 8055.

This works , but still , there's a problem , everytime I input :

- The IP of the server , without any port >> it redirects me to www.my_domain.com:8055 ( **which is bad , because I'd want to hide the port from HTTPS version of my website**)
- The IP of the server + ":8049" >> it redirects me to IP:8049 ( **which is good** )
- The IP of the server + ":8055" >> it doesn't redirect me anywhere , no response ( **which is bad , I think , shouldn't it redirect me to the HTTPS version [ e.g : www.my_domain.com ] ?** )
- The "www.my_domain.com" or "my_domain.com" >> it redirects me to www.my_domain.com:8055 ( **which is bad , because I'd want to hide the port from HTTPS version of my website**)

I'll paste below the current nginx configuration I have :

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
       worker_connections 768;
    }

    http {

       sendfile on;
       tcp_nopush on;
       tcp_nodelay on;
       keepalive_timeout 65;
       types_hash_max_size 2048;

       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type application/octet-stream;

       # These 2 lines is what I tried , from what I've seen on stackoverflow , it didn't work...
       port_in_redirect off;
       server_name_in_redirect off;

       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";

       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    }
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
    server {

       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       listen 443 ssl default_server;
       listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
       root /var/www/html;
       server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;
       location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8055;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       }
       ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my_domain.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my_domain.key;
       return 301 https://www.my_domain.com$request_uri;
    }
```

**No files in /etc/nginx/conf.d**

Nginx version : `nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

OS : `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-186-generic x86_64)`

What should I do to remove the PORT from the HTTPS URL and to make the IP:8055 accesible ( the third bullet point ) ?

**The output of nginx -T :**

```
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        port_in_redirect off;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                port_in_redirect off;
                #server_name_in_redirect off;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my_domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my_domain.key;
        return 301 https://www.my_domain.com$request_uri;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/proxy_params:
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed , the solution was to add the following thing , inside `/nginx/sites-enabled` :

```
upstream nodejs {
    server localhost:8049;                
}

location @nodejs {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header Host $host ;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location / {
    ....
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
}
```